# Make specific pandas column rows become a calculated column

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, group-by

I am trying to make a the specific values in one pandas row each have their own aggregation column in a data frame. The tables current state looks like this:

```
    import pandas as pd

data = {'Month':  ['2020-12-01', '2020-12-01', '2021-01-01', '2021-01-01'],
        'Group': ['a', 'b','a', 'b'],
        'channel': ['cbs', 'fox','cbs', 'fox'],
        'viewership': ['10k', '15k','12k','6k'],
        'rating': ['1', '3.2','1.2','2.1'],
       
         
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

print(df)

[image: current state]

and the desired state is to have the channel row values become aggregation columns, meaning the channel column table will go away and instead the table will look as follows.

```
data1 = {'Month':  ['2020-12-01', '2020-12-01', '2021-01-01', '2021-01-01'],
   

     'Group': ['a', 'b','a' 'b'],
            'cbs_ viewership': ['10k', '15k','12k','6k'],
             'fox_ viewership': ['10k', '15k','12k','6k'],
            'cbs_rating': ['1', '3.2','1.2','2.1'],
             'fox_rating': ['1', '3.2','1.2','2.1'],
           
             
            }
    
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

print(df1)
```

[image: desired state]

4 new columns (cbs_ viewership,fox_ viewership,cbs_rating,fox_rating) are created and take on the channel row column name and values

Answer (score 0):

You can apply [`pd.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df = df.pivot(columns='channel', index=['Month','Group']).swaplevel(0, 1, axis=1)\
    .stack().fillna(method='ffill', axis=1)\
    .fillna(method='bfill', axis=1).unstack()\
    .pipe(lambda x: x.set_axis(x.columns.map('_'.join), axis=1))\
    .reset_index()
print(df)
```

---

```
        Month Group cbs_rating cbs_viewership fox_rating fox_viewership
0  2020-12-01     a          1            10k          1            10k
1  2020-12-01     b        3.2            15k        3.2            15k
2  2021-01-01     a        1.2            12k        1.2            12k
3  2021-01-01     b        2.1             6k        2.1             6k
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I expand this to my dataset I am receiving an error "Index contains duplicate entries", is there some type of aggregation that is required between the month and group index?

Comment: @Philo, does your actual `df` contain duplicated pairs of `Month - Group` entries? If so, do they have the same duplicated values on all other remaining columns?

Comment: I have a few month-group duplicates but they have different rating and viewership values

Comment: @Philo, add/update an extended sample  to your question

Comment: Hi Roman, I fixed the duplicate issue by adding an additional column to the df, using the code line (df.insert(0,"row", np.arange(1,len(df)+1)). This way I created a work around that makes each row unique